# Redirect to another page in PHP through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My page is gathering info from javascript and sending it to PHP and then to MySQL, issue is that i want it to redirect to different pages depending on the data i have in the DB, I've tried to use header but it just shows me the whole HTML code of the other page in the alert and I don't want that. I want it to redirect to one page or another depending on the condition

HTML (Login.html)

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
<input class="input100" type="text" id="user" name="username" placeholder="Email">
<span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
<input class="input100" type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
<span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
</div>

<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
<a class="login100-form-btn" id = "logBtn">
Login
</a>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('#logBtn').click(function(event){ 
    user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"login.php",
        async: false,
        data: {user:user,password:password},
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        //window.location = '../Main/index.html';
        }
        });
    });
```

PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "tbjdjkdl";
$dbname = "dbbbbbb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass' AND permisos='Administrador'";
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "admin";
        header('Location: ../Main/index.html');
        exit;
    }
    else{
    echo "user";
    header('Location: ../Main/startemp.html');
    exit;
    }

 } else {
    $msg = "username/password invalid";
    echo $msg;
 }

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Never ever use $_POST variables directly for SQL queries! This makes SQL injection very easy!

Comment: @PeterKraume What should I use?

Comment: Never trust input data! You need to validate and sanitize your parameters. See https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_filter.asp as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proper AJAX format to handle the response in client side here is the modified code

login.html

```
      <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
      <input class="input100" type="text" id="user" name="username" placeholder="Email">
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
      <input class="input100" type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
      <a class="login100-form-btn" id = "logBtn">
      Login
      </a>
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $('#logBtn').click(function(event){ 
          user = document.getElementById("user").value;
          password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

          $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:"login.php",
              async: false,
              data: {user:user,password:password},
              success: function(data){
              alert(data);
          if(data=="admin"){
                  window.location="https://..Main/index.html";
                }
        if(data=="user"){
                  window.location="https://....startemp.html";
                }
              }
              });
          });

      </script>
```

login.php

```
      <?php

      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "root";
      $dbname = "test";

      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $pass = $_POST['password'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass'"; 

      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass' AND permisos='Administrador'";
           $result_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_1);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($result_1) > 0){

              echo "admin";
              exit(0);
            }
             else{
          echo "user"; 
           exit(0);
          }

       } else {
          $msg = "username/password invalid";
          echo $msg;
       }

      mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use proper JSON format to handle the response in client side here is the modified code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "tbjdjkdl";
$dbname = "dbbbbbb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass' AND permisos='Administrador'";
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'url' => '../Main/index.html']);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'url' => '../Main/startemp.html']);
        exit;
    }
} else {
    $msg = "username/password invalid";
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'msg' => $msg]);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Your JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#logBtn').click(function (event) {
        user = document.getElementById("user").value;
        password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            async: false,
            data: {user: user, password: password},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status === 'success')
                    window.location.href = data.url; //Just do the redirection here
                } else {
                    //Do your failiure stuff
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It always enters in the failure condition in the AJAX, it never becomes "success", I tried to do an alert of the data.status in the AJAX and it's always undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON type of response to the Ajax Request so that the Ajax callback will handle the redirection.

SCRIPT

```
$('#logBtn').click(function(event){ 
    user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"login.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        data: {
            user:user,
            password:password
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.message);
            alert(data.redirect);
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "tbjdjkdl";
$dbname = "dbbbbbb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$return = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass' AND permisos='Administrador'";
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $return = array(
            "message" => "admin",
            "redirect" => "../Main/index.html";
        );
    }
    else{
        $return = array(
            "message" => "user",
            "redirect" => "../Main/startemp.html";
        );
    }

} else {
    $return = array(
        "message" => "username/password invalid",
        "redirect" => "";
    );
}

echo json_encode($return);
mysqli_close($conn);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: all the alerts are "undefined"

Edit: I forgot to put dataType: "JSON", but now that I did it does nothing, not even the alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#logBtn').click(function(event){ 
    user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"login.php",
        async: false,
        data: {user:user,password:password},
        success: function(data){
             if(data == 'admin'){
                window.location.href='../Main/index.html';
             }
             elseif(data == 'user'){
                window.location.href='../Main/startemp.html';
             }else{
               alert(data);
             }
        });
    });
```

//please remove the line header() on login.php;

Comment: it's doing nothing, it doesn't even show me the alert