# Checking if Username and Password is match or available - Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm having a problem on my code which the username and password does not match.
Here is my output. When the username and password is not match, then it will give a message that it is **not match** , However, when the username and password match, then there will be a message that it is **match** here is my code below:

[image: Image here]

**html code**

```
<body>  
  <div class="container box">  
   <div class="form-group">  
    <h3 align="center">Live Username Available or not By using PHP Ajax Jquery</h3><br />  
    <label>Enter Username</label>  
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />

    <span id="availability"></span>
    <br /><br />
    <button type="button" name="register" class="btn btn-info" id="register" disabled>Register</button>
    <br />
   </div>  
   <br />  
   <br />  
  </div>  
 </body>  
</html>
```

**script code**

```
  <script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  
       $('#username','#password').blur(function(){

         var username = $(this).val();
         var password = $(this).val();

         $.ajax({
          url:'check.php',
          method:"POST",
          data:{user_name:username, password:password},
          success:function(data)
          {
           if(data != '1')
           {
            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Username and Password not Match</span>');
            $('#register').attr("disabled", true);
           }
           else
           {
            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success">Username and Password Available</span>');
            $('#register').attr("disabled", false);
           }
          }
         })

      });
     });  
    </script>
```

**check.php** - my database connection and query that fetch it from the database

```
 <?php  
    //check.php  
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "", "dbname"); 
    if(isset($_POST["user_name"] && $_POST["password"]))
    {
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["user_name"]);
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);
     $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' ";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: And what is the output from `console.log(data)` in success callback function??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef when I remove the password the program works correctly just by username the program works fine, but when I added the password then it is not working cannot get data from `console.log` I am not sure about this `if(isset($_POST["user_name"] && $_POST["password"]))`  and this `$('#username','#password').blur(function(){`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034740/redirect-to-another-page-in-php-through-ajax/56035009#56035009

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef just to inform you sir, that code is a tutorial from this site [Check username availability](https://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/how-to-check-username-availability-in.html). I just modify and change it to make two inputs which is the password then it is not working correctly.

Comment: @Nick answer the `jquery selector` and `isset` part .. but to let you know .. **didn't work** is not a good thing to describe the problem specially with `ajax` . With AJAX. 1- check the connection between the js and the php file .. 2- `console.log` the returned data .. 3- pass variables from js to php .. then echo it out in php and it should return in a returned data .. 4- Add the db part then check the data again and again to output the desired output  .. Last thing to be accurate trim the data before any if statement  `var data = data.trim();` to avoid any unwanted white spaces

Answer (score 1):

**Notes**

- You are wide open to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements instead. Please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- You should not store passwords in plain text. Instead, use PHP's [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions to hash and verify.

**Answer**

You are using [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) incorrectly. To check that multiple values are set, separate them by commas, not with `&&`:

```
if(isset($_POST["user_name"], $_POST["password"]))
```

Your PHP code as it currently stands won't produce any output as it will terminate with a fatal error on that line.

In your jQuery, you're not specifying multiple selectors correctly. They should all be inside the same set of quotes:

```
$('#username, #password').blur(function(){
```

You also need to change this code, which will set both `username` and `password` values to the same thing:

```
var username = $(this).val();
var password = $(this).val();
```

to

```
var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
```

Comment: can you check on the jquery code as well please ?  thank you sir

Comment: im not sure about this line sir, `$('#username','#password').blur(function(){`

Comment: @webccodez your jQuery has a problem too. See my edit.

Comment: sir, great thing is the message is now showing `Username and Password not Match` although even I input the correct username and password. it is still not saying it is **Match** can we see it more thoroughly please sir thank you .. we're closed to it i guess??

Comment: What is the output from `console.log(data)` in the callback function?

Comment: the output is `0`

Comment: That is saying that you didn't get a match. Are you sure you're entering values that are in the database? If not, it's probably due to your use of `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the username and password fields, so try removing those lines and see what happens.

Comment: how about this line sir `if(data != '1')` do you think that is the conflict? can you please see this line      `if(data != '0')
           {
            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Username and Password not Match</span>');
            $('#register').attr("disabled", true);
           }
           else
           {
            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success">Username and Password Available</span>');
            $('#register').attr("disabled", false);
           }`

Comment: @webccodez no, the value of `data` is 0, indicating no match in the database, and that code is working fine. Please try what I said in my last comment.

Comment: already did :( then console.log does not return anything even 0 or 1. it is blank.. how about in the ajax or in the jquery sir? or in the query?

Comment: See my note about another issue with your jQuery code.

Comment: still didnt match sir. :(

Comment: ok, you need to provide more useful information than "still didnt match sir.". I can't help debug that. Try putting some debug statements in your PHP, then `console.log(data)` in the success function and see if what is in your PHP is what you expect.

Comment: to provide more help sir please see the image above on what my console and what my UI looks like please thank you sir,

Comment: That doesn't help at all. Please do what I asked and put debugging statements in your PHP and then `console.log(data)` to see what they say

Comment: Nick , yes :( but the datat always put into `0` sorry sir